# What does "$<" & "$>" mean in Perl

Tags: perl, variables

An example will be highly appreciated. Below is a sample of where I read it:

```
$self->parameter(
    name => 'real_user',
    xpath => undef, 
    default => scalar(getpwuid($<))
);
$self->parameter(
    name => 'production',
    xpath => '/config/production', 
    default => $self->get('user_uid') == $>
);
```

Comment: You can check perldoc for perl built-in variables thusly `perldoc -v $<`

Comment: @doubleDown: You need to quote the argument: `perldoc -v '$<'`

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes my bad. I forgot about that in all the excitement.

Comment: @doubleDown: You have a low threshold of excitement. 8-)}

Comment: lol. But looks like it didn't work in our corp's environment

Answer (score 13):

A `$` followed by symbol? To [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)!

> `$<`
>   The real uid of this process.
>
> `$>`
>   The effective uid of this process.

Use them to find out what user is running the program.

Answer (score 7):

From perldoc: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

```
$<
```

The real uid of this process. You can change both the real uid and the effective uid at the same time by using `POSIX::setuid()` . Since changes to `$<` require a system call, check `$!` after a change attempt to detect any possible errors.

Mnemonic: it's the uid you came from, if you're running setuid.

```
$>
```

The effective uid of this process. For example:

```
$< = $>;            # set real to effective uid    
($<,$>) = ($>,$<);  # swap real and effective uids
```

You can change both the effective uid and the real uid at the same time by using `POSIX::setuid()` . Changes to `$>` require a check to `$!` to detect any possible errors after an attempted change.

$< and $> can be swapped only on machines supporting setreuid() .

Mnemonic: it's the uid you went to, if you're running setuid.